# Android studio , build gradle failed to find dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have some problems in android studio and gradle...
First of all I should mention that I download [IFixit android project](https://github.com/iFixit/iFixitAndroid) which is open source and import some part of it in my project, but something is wrong. When I add dependencies in my project and building gradle cause error for Failng To Find !!! for example below is two of them :

```
compile "com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:pulltorefresh:2.1.2"
compile 'com.marczych.androidsectionheaders:androidsectionheaders:1.0.0'
```

I solve some of the errors by changing the name but above files doesnt work at all!!! something that is strange for me is that my build.gradle file use jcenter() repository but IFixit ones use mavenCentaral() and actually i don't know what is the difference !i add mavenCentral() to my repository but nothing happened !

I change first link to :

```
compile "com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library:2.1.1"
```

and gradle build succesfully but my activity class can not resolve import like this :

```
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;
```

and doenst know the classes !

I should mention that i use android studio v0.8.6 and gradle:0.13.+ (2.1) and minimum required sdk for my project is 4.0

Is there any way to solve my problem and import dependencies without error ?
I will appreciate any suggestion ...
thanks in advance ...

UPDATE (Solution):

I solved the problem by adding below line into my repositories :

```
maven {
  url 'https://raw.github.com/iFixit/ark/master/releases/'
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting when running Gradle?

Comment: this is the error : Error:Failed to find: com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:pulltorefresh:2.1.2

Comment: @Evil from where did you get that maven url ?

Comment: that was from an opensource project on github...

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the '+' symbol when you specify the version of the dependency you need, this will get you the "latest" version available.

for instance

`compile "com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library:2.+"`  would get you the latest 2.x version
`compile "com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library:+"`  would get you the latest one availabe x.x version

however this is not quite "recommended" for projects that are constantly updating repos with nightly builds since something unstable might come up and affect the project, but sometimes it might be "ok".

Best.

Comment: I try your suggestion, and gradle build succesfully, but there is a problem and that is there is an error in activity, says: cannot resolve symbol : import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView... actually it cannot resolve classes like PullToRefreshListView!

Comment: I have checked this library you are using, on its site https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh it states that it is no longer being maintained, as I said using + is not recommended since it might download buggy nightly builds, which is very much probably your case. I would suggest you search for an alternate library which is actually being maintained. That being said, the problem is not your gradle at all, it's the lack of maintenance to this pulltorefresh library

Comment: thank you, but as I mentioned, I reuse an open source project from github and this project use that library !!! and it shouldn't be wrong because the project is avaliable still ...

Comment: also what's wrong with other dependency ?! I think something is wrong about the gradle or maybe I missing some part of code !

Comment: No problem, but I sincerely doubt Gradle is the problem, if that is the case perhaps the best thing to do is to do some research for an "stable" of this library, or perhaps there is some problem in the code that doesn't allow gradle to compile. If Gradle was the problem then you wouldn't be able to compile nothing at all. Perhaps you should try compiling a jar from the various tags available for Android-PullToRefresh on Github, and use a compile file on gradle once you have created your own jar from these tags. I'm sure one might work

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the errors, number of things stand out:

1. `com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase` class is not in `com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library` but in `com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:sample`.
2. There is no published version of 2.1.2 of `pulltorefresh`. The latest is [2.1.1](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh%3Asample/view).

Based on that, I'd propose you adding both `com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library` and `com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:library` (and maybe `com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh:extras` as well) to your dependencies, all of version 2.1.1. Should probably do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I add three libraries (:library, :sample, :extras) all in version 2.1.1 and the gradle build successfully without any error, but the problem is that the classes PullToRefreshBase and PullToRefreshListView cannot resolved  :( where are these two classes? (I add import statement for them but doesn't resolve import too!)

Comment: `PullToRefreshBase` class resides in `sample`. If build passes, that means that your classpath is correct. Try to refresh the Gradle sync, should solve it.

Comment: it says package does not exists :( I can't import PullToRefreshBase  `import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;` ...

Comment: can you look at this [link(https://github.com/iFixit/iFixitAndroid) and see how they can add pulltorefresh version 2.1.2 and where is it ?! thanks in advance ...

Comment: The import doesn't work cause you need to refresh your IDE classpath. Where they took 2.1.2 from I don't know. It's not published on JCenter, nor on Maven Central.